# Issues with minification

Tags: javascript, angularjs, sockjs

I decided to switch from socketIO to sockjs for my Angularjs app. I never had problems building my project before (with socketIO) which involves minification and concat but when I build my project now I think that this file is giving me issues which is from here: https://github.com/bendrucker/angular-sockjs as it's the only new file.

```
/*
* angular-sockjs v0.0.1
* (c) 2014 Ben Drucker http://bendrucker.me
* Based on https://github.com/btford/angular-socket-io
* License: MIT
*/

'use strict';

angular.module('bd.sockjs', [])
.provider('socketFactory', function () {

// when forwarding events, prefix the event name
var ioSocket;

// expose to provider
this.$get = function ($timeout) {

  var asyncAngularify = function (socket, callback) {
    return callback ? function () {
      var args = arguments;
      $timeout(function () {
        callback.apply(socket, args);
      }, 0);
    } : angular.noop;
  };

  return function socketFactory (options) {
    options = options || {};
    var socket = options.socket || new SockJS(options.url);

    var wrappedSocket = {
      callbacks: {},
      setHandler: function (event, callback) {
        socket['on' + event] = asyncAngularify(socket, callback);
        return this;
      },
      removeHandler: function(event) {
        delete socket['on' + event];
        return this;
      },
      send: function () {
        return socket.send.apply(socket, arguments);
      },
      close: function () {
        return socket.close.apply(socket, arguments);
      }
    };

    return wrappedSocket;
  };
};
});
```

Is there any reason why this file won't minify?
I am aware of the typical Angularjs minification issues so I've used string-injection syntax in all of my files. However, I can't see an opportunity to do that with this file and there isn't a minified file included with the Bower install.

This is the error in the browser console which looks to me like an injection issue:

**Error: [$injector:unpr] http://errors.angularjs.org/1.3.0-beta.13/$injector/unpr?p0=aProvider%20%3C-%20a%20%3C-ocketFactory%20%3C-%socket**

**UPDATE:**
To test that it was this file causing the issue I hosted the file on a CDN instead of minifying it. Everything works fine now so it must be this file causing the issue. It would be interesting to know what the problem is if anyone comes across this question.

Comment: Is there an issue because $timeout is used in the $get function definition? I'd think you'd want to use this.get = ['$timeout', function($timeout) { ... } ];

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solved this on [Github](https://github.com/bendrucker/angular-sockjs/issues/3). @efeder was mostly correct (although it's `this.$get` and not `this.get`). The issue is that v0.0.1 didn't have proper annotations but v0.1 (latest) fixed that.